# Synapse Analytics Querying one column from Parquet does not reduce size of data retrieved?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

When I query a SQL Serverless Database created in Synapse Analytics, I thought that querying only one field would reduce the size of data scanned since Parquet files are columnar by nature but it only slightly reduces the size?

[image]

[image]

[image][image]